# github installation on mac

Tags: github, terminal

I installed GitHub on mac but I don't have installed git on terminal. When I type git on terminal it prints command not found.

```
George-Kankavas-MacBook-Pro:~ georgekankava$ git
```

-bash: git: command not found

Comment: What version of Mac OS X ? Did you install the developer tools (Xcode) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install it from here http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3

Comment: He shouldn't need to install git - it's installed by default if you have a reasonably current version of OS X and Xcode installed.

Comment: who is saying anything about Xcode? Maybe he is not using it. he shouldn't install it just for git support.

Comment: if Xcode is installed can you run `which git` in the terminal to check where git is installed

Comment: thanks, I removed old one and installed from link above. It work fine now :)

Answer (score 3):

GitHub application doesn't include git binary (it uses [ObjectiveGit framework](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git)).

To install git console utility on your machine you can:

- Install Xcode (git is included into [Xcode4 from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/)), you have to register account on apple.com)
- **OR** Download [Git for OS X](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/)

**UPD**

Little note: I'm not sure if git already included in Xcode3 since Xcode IDE supports Git only since version 4. So, in case you have Xcode3 installed and don't plan to upgrade to Xcode4 you  can install [Git for OS X](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) or install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and install git from it (sudo port install git-core)

Comment: regardless of whether he is able to get git onto his system by other means, this doesn't help if the commands he wants to use in Git are supposed to be related to his GitHub for Mac client? Is he expected to choose between a command line installation of Git or a GUI? That doesn't seem fair.